# Rhomobile: Updating Notification/Status Bar

Tags: javascript, ruby, rhomobile

I am writing an app where I have an item with an expiry date. I want to check the expiry date and if it is in the past, put a message in the notification/status bar (icon and message).

This sounds trivial, but I am struggling to find any code snippets that demonstrate how to update the notification/status bar.

Does anyone have any code or a walkthrough on how to achieve this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vibrate, Beeper, LED Flash or a popup. Please refer the link http://docs.rhomobile.com/en/4.0.0/guide/device_hardware_key_handling for further details.